# Trying to import tensorflow into VSCode, but getting a NoModuleFouNdError

Tags: python, visual-studio, tensorflow, visual-studio-code

I am using anaconda with VSCode. I import tensorflow after I downloaded it and made sure I was in the correct environment, but everytime I run the program in the terminal in both VSCode and the regular terminal I am getting this error saying no module name tensorflow. it will work in jupyter notebook perfectly without running into the error. I have tried launching VSCode from the anaconda navigator as well nothing is working. What am I doing wrong?

I am using python 3.9.7 with the recommended version from google of tensorflow 2.6

Answer (score 0):

see if your python interpreter path is correct. And u can edit if u click on this at the left bottom corner of vs code.

[image]

Click on this [image]and vs code will show u all python interpreters it found all if your path is not there u can select it manually

Comment: I tried that and it's in the correct environment but it is still giving me the error. I went in and even checked to see if tensor flow was installed and it's right there next to all the packages it requires. I think I have made the decision to just start using jupyter notebook instead. A lot less headaches will be had by doing that.

Comment: another thing u can try is to open the folder of the virtual environment via open folder and then select the right interpreter

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked which python environment you are using in the terminal?

```
get-command python
pip --version
pip show tensorflow
```

And which python interpreter you have selected in the Jupyter NoteBook？

Comment: he did read the comments under my answer

Answer (score 0):

After installing `VS code` in your system, You need to install [python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) for `VS code`. Then click on "Create new Jupyter notebook" and select the appropriate Python interpreter(virtual environment) as in Anaconda to run the `TensorFlow` code.

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71828411/tensorflow-is-partially-imported) similar issue for your reference.