# GPU for TensorFlow detected in conda environment, but not in Jupyter notebook (vscode)

Tags: tensorflow, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed TensorFlow as described on [this page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) in WSL.

The final test after installing is succesfull and the GPU is detected by TensorFlow:

```bash
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
2022-12-14 15:40:40.633322: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-12-14 15:40:41.288334: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: :/home/miepi/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/
2022-12-14 15:40:41.288439: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: :/home/miepi/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/
2022-12-14 15:40:41.288485: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
2022-12-14 15:40:41.778389: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:967] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2022-12-14 15:40:41.786330: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:967] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2022-12-14 15:40:41.786752: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:967] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

But using the same conda environment in vscode the gpu isn't detected:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
```

Output:

```
2022-12-14 15:52:40.605584: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-12-14 15:52:40.702419: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-12-14 15:52:40.702451: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2022-12-14 15:52:41.280631: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-12-14 15:52:41.280716: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-12-14 15:52:41.280726: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
```

```py
# Check if GPU is available
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

Output:

```
[]
Num GPUs Available:  0
2022-12-14 15:52:43.871361: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:967] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2022-12-14 15:52:43.871484: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-12-14 15:52:43.871536: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcublas.so.11'; dlerror: libcublas.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-12-14 15:52:43.871577: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcublasLt.so.11'; dlerror: libcublasLt.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-12-14 15:52:43.871617: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcufft.so.10'; dlerror: libcufft.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-12-14 15:52:43.871656: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcurand.so.10'; dlerror: libcurand.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-12-14 15:52:43.871694: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusolver.so.11'; dlerror: libcusolver.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-12-14 15:52:43.871734: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusparse.so.11'; dlerror: libcusparse.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-12-14 15:52:43.871772: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudnn.so.8'; dlerror: libcudnn.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-12-14 15:52:43.871781: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1934] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
```

Does anybody have an idea, what I could try to fix this issue? Or what I could have done wrong?

- I already checked if the correct kernel is selected in vscode.
- And the correct interpreter is set for the workspace as well.
- Jupyter is installed in the environment

Could it be possible that this step from the tutorial is not working for the jupyter kernel in vscode?

```bash
mkdir -p $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CONDA_PREFIX/lib/' > $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh
```

But I don't know how to set that up in vscode.

Comment: Could you please try again by installing [python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) for `VS code`. Have a look at this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72137876/14290681) for the reference. Let us know if the issue still persists. Thank You