# How can I get Keras to run on GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am just getting started with neural networks, and have a CNN that I want to speed up by running the process on my GPU. However I am having a lot of difficulty setting this up, different websites and tutorials I go to seem to be out of date or deprecated, and I keep getting led down rabbit holes and ending up nowhere.

I imported python and all of my modules including numpy, keras, etc., have been installing using pip and am running the code using visual studio code.

I have followed a few tutorials that seemed to have me updating/installing drivers, installing visual studio, installing the cuda toolkit, installing zlib, installing cuDNN, setting path variables and copying files since automatic installers were not there. And at this point I got stuck in understanding what I am doing and am very lost. If anyone has any advice or can reference an up to date tutorial please let me know! Primarily I was following this tutorial: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html?ncid=em-prod-337416, and got stuck at step 2.3.5, since I don't really know how visual studio works(I just installed it). It seems I am doing something really off so I would appreciate any advice or help even if you are uncertain!

Comment: Advise. Yes, sure. Use linux. More specifically. Use Lambda labs stack to set up GPU acceleration. If you can set up a dual boot ubuntu. You can install Lambda stack. Windows in my experience, is just harder.

Comment: You don’t need to use Visual Studio like that if you are not going to *compile* code yourself which uses cudnn. If you only want to run frameworks already built with cudnn support, you just need to install the runtime libraries

Comment: @talonmies I am creating my own cnns from scratch using keras,, and compiling it on my own computer.

Comment: @Quant1892387 Do you have any advice for windows, or any place I can go to for good advice? I think it would cause more long run difficulties if I switched operating systems, considering windows is what I run everything else on and all I know.

Comment: What does `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` give you? [According to documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu) keras and tensorflow will run on a single GPU without any code changes. Have you seen [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662253/can-i-run-keras-model-on-gpu)?

Comment: Yes, sure. I understand. Thats why I suggested a dual boot. That means, when you turn the computer on you'll be asked to pick an operating system. There is a learning curve but, if you're serious about this. The people on 'top' do not use windows. Your hesitation is very valid. Staying in Windows is very doable and a solid choice. My advise still stands. There will other benefits in the future. Regardless, if you put the work, you will get there.

Answer (score 1):

Please try again by following the step by step instructions mentioned in this [TF install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#hardware_requirements) page to install tensorflow in your system and check all the **Hardware/System requirements** satisfied to setup GPU support with Tensorflow.

Please ensure you have installed `python 3.7-3.10` and `tensorflow <=2.10` to setup tensorflow GPU on Windows because ***GPU support on native-Windows is only available for 2.10 or earlier versions, starting in TF 2.11, CUDA build is not supported for Windows*** as mentioned in this [tested build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu).

Now try installing and launching the VScode from the same conda VirEnv where you have installed tensorflow and performed GPU setup.

Please check this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71828411/tensorflow-is-partially-imported/72137876#72137876) for your reference.